# How to check if values are changing in the right order? C++

Tags: c++, arduino

I need a way to check that these pins change from HIGH to LOW in right order. (i.e. RED > BROWN > BLUE > GREY > BLACK > YELLOW > WHITE > ORANGE > PURPLE > GREEN) If one of the pins change out of order, it has to add 1 to "errorCount" if error count exceeds 4 then call a function.

Part of code for pins:

```
  const int wire_BROWN =  30;
  int wire_BROWN_state = 0;
  int wire_BROWN_lastState = 0;

  const int wire_RED =    32;
  int wire_RED_state = 0;
  int wire_RED_lastState = 0;

  const int wire_ORANGE = 34;
  int wire_ORANGE_state = 0;
  int wire_ORANGE_lastState = 0;

  const int wire_YELLOW = 36;
  int wire_YELLOW_state = 0;
  int wire_YELLOW_lastState = 0;

  const int wire_GREEN =  38;
  int wire_GREEN_state = 0;
  int wire_GREEN_lastState = 0;

  const int wire_BLUE =   40;
  int wire_BLUE_state = 0;
  int wire_BLUE_lastState = 0;

  const int wire_PURPLE = 42;
  int wire_PURPLE_state = 0;
  int wire_PURPLE_lastState = 0;

  const int wire_GREY =   44;
  int wire_GREY_state = 0;
  int wire_GREY_lastState = 0;

  const int wire_WHITE =  46;
  int wire_WHITE_state = 0;
  int wire_WHITE_lastState = 0;

  const int wire_BLACK =  48;
  int wire_BLACK_state = 0;
  int wire_BLACK_lastState = 0;
```

Comment: Setup a finite state machine.

Answer (score 1):

You could put them in an array in the order that you want to check them in, and then loop through the array, running a check

Pseudocode:

```
byte check(int a[]){ // Get's called on update of pins
    byte error = 0;
    for (byte i=1; i < a.length - 1; a++);
    if (a[i] < a[i-1]){
       error++;
    }
    return(error)
}

byte stateArray[] = {
  digitalRead(wire_BROWN),
  digitalRead(wire_BLUE),
  digitalRead(wire_BLACK),
  digitalRead(wire_YELLOW),
  digitalRead(wire_WHITE),
  digitalRead(wire_ORANGE),
  digitalRead(wire_PURPLE),
  digitalRead(wire_GREEN),
};
byte errorCount = check(stateArray);
if (errorCount > 4) {
    // Error Handling
}
```

Comment: That's a very minimal (and ineffective form) of a state machine? ;-)

Comment: @stark Well, FSMs can be implemented in many various forms, no? switch/case, table lookup (which this merely is), State Pattern, ...

Comment: Please, please, please, STOP USING INTs for everything... In this case byte is more than enough (you have to count up to 8, and the digitalRead function does not return values bigger than 256, so avoid using ints.... Moreover your code does the opposite of what the OP wants (you are checking for low-to-high transitions, whereas the OP wants to monitor the high-to-low one